# Prefab Instantiate performance improvment

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, optimization, prefab

so I have a multiple category buttons in every category there is more than 20 items. So make prefab and instantiate when button is pressed. The problem is When I instantiate prefab I have to initialize it with info like name, sprite, btn click event etc. this will take time to instantiate prefabs and game hangs. Here is code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < prefab.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(basePrefab) as GameObject;
            go.SetActive(true);
            go.transform.SetParent(prefabParent, false);
            go.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            go.GetComponent<Category>().Init(prefab[i]);
        }
```

This code is called in button click. Alternatively to achieve some performance in start method I already instantiate some basePrefab on a empty gameobject and on button click just change parent and initialize them. this approach will give some benefits but still game is hangs for 2 sec here is that code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < prefab.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = InstantiatedGameObject[i];
            go.SetActive(true);
            go.transform.SetParent(prefabParent, false);
            go.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            go.GetComponent<Category>().Init(prefab[i]);
        }
```

Any solution to improve performance ??

So Here is About prefab contenet: Basically prefab contains Background image, Mask image in this image Catgory image, Selection image, and
a Text.  In init function the category image change and Text value change Also Background contains button in init set this button's click event [image: Here is image]

Comment: Have you tried to do this in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know maximum quantity of categories and category items you don't have to instantiate them. You can use slots that you activate and deactivate based on the amount of items. During activation you can also bind and unbind them to objects which you can use to assign correct sprites and texts to your button elements.

If you don't know the quantity of category items in advance you can still do the same but using pagination which can be preferable from user perspective as well if there's a lot of items.

```cs
public class SomeUI : MonoBehavior
{
    public GameObject categorySlotsParent;
    public GameObject categoryItemSlotsParent;
    public Category[] categories;
    
    CategorySlot[] categorySlots;
    CategoryItemSlot[] categoryItemSlots;

    public void Awake(){
        
        categorySlots = GetComponentsInChildren<CategorySlot>();
        categoryItemSlots = GetComponentsInChildren<CategoryItemSlot>();
        AssignCategories(categories);
        
        if(categories.Length > 0 && categories[0] != null)
            SelectCategory(categories[0]);
    }
    
    void AssignCategories(Category[] categories){
        
        for(int i = 0; i < categorySlots.Length;  i++){
            if(i < categories.Length)
            {
                categorySlots[i].SetActive(true);
                categorySlots[i].AssignCategory(categories[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                categorySlots[i].SetActive(false);
                categorySlots[i].AssignCategory(null);
            }
        }
    }
    
    void AssignCategoryItems(CategoryItem[] categoryItems){
        
        for(int i = 0; i < categorySlots.Length;  i++)
        {
            if(i < categoryItems.Length)
            {
                categoryItemSlots[i].SetActive(true);
                categoryItemSlots[i].AssignCategoryItem(categoryItems[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                categoryItemSlots[i].SetActive(false);
                categoryItemSlots[i].AssignCategoryItem(null);
            }
        }
    }
    
    void SelectCategory(Category category){
        AssignCategoryItems(category.categoryItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you still want to instantiate the items you'll have to use profiler to see what is causing the hangs and fix it or divide the instantiation process to span multiple frames using co-routines or something.

Comment: This is interesting. I will try it but in current situation i added this prefabs in scrollrect so user can scroll through it horizontally. I actually use profiler  it seems scroll bar takes too much time to update. I used `scrollrect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0f;` which is cause issue

Comment: I've used this with ScrollRects that have children using ContentSizeFitter and LayoutGroups and it works fine. Might take a while to find good hierachy and elements with dynamic size might require some extra tweaks. Actually moved to this pattern due to having many issues with ScrollRects, layoutgroups and contentsize fitter handling instantiated objects back in the day when UGUI launched and have used ever since.

Answer (score 0):

If your instantiated object is a common object , you can improved it pooling the prefab avoiding to instantiate & destroy this object each time. You have a good example of workflow [here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling#5ff8d015edbc2a002063971e)

Comment: I already implemented this in a second code it save some time but there is a still performance issue. First time I click button it will take some time after that it runs perfectly every time I click button

Comment: where You preload it  pool?

Comment: Hey there I already preload it in a empty gameobject and add it in a InstantiatedGameObject array, as you can see in my second code